# Restsharp - Cannot get error response body

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, restsharp

I am using current (106.5.4) version of RestSharp with Xamarin.iOS and MvvmCross. I works very well (automatic body serialization, deserialization etc.), however I am having hard time getting error response body.

If there is a response from server with error code 4xx or 5xx I get just strange exception in top level of my code that says

> "Error getting response stream (ReadAsync): ReceiveFailure Value
>   cannot be null. Parameter name: src"

Only when I use "Catch All Exceptions" in visual studio I can see the real exception down in call stack. Even though there is no way how to access the body. Accessing the body would be extremely helpful because the server can say there what is wrong with the request.

Am I missing anything, or there is no way in RestSharp?
Thank you for any response